# Windows phone HTML 5 app , google map api , permission denied error

Tags: html, google-maps, windows-phone-8

I am trying a sample for google map api in a Windows phone 8.1 HTML5 App.  But when I run it in emulator, it throws me "Permission denied". What am I missing ?

Note : I am not able to copy the code below but it is the same code in this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14145167/googlemap-with-geolocation-not-showing-up) (Code in 1st Answer). Basically I take that code and paste it in my index.html page and run the emulator.

- Girija

---

Answer (score 1):

Sorry same question was asked twice. This question is duplicate of the same question here :

[Windows phone 8.1 HTML5 app , using google map api throws me "permission denied" error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25292010/windows-phone-8-1-html5-app-using-google-map-api-throws-me-permission-denied)